# HttpUrlConnection setTimeOut is not working properly and Timeout will occur earlier

Tags: java, jboss, httpurlconnection

Hi I am using HttpUrlconnection to send request to my devices from my application. The application is running on jboss server.

When i set connectionTimeout as 30000 (30 seconds) in HttpUrlconnction.setConnectionTimeout(30000), it's no working properly. The connection timeout has been happened earlier and exception thrown at 9 seconds.

Does any one know that, how to solve this.

Reference code is below

```
       URL url = new URL("http://.....");

       HttpURLConnection urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: I think I am encountering same thing, it times out way earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.setReadTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
```